# Extract complete content from xml with Tika

Tags: xml, apache, apache-tika

I want to extract the complete content of an xml file with tika. That means that tika should not take the text out of the elements and throw the tags away.

The ouput of the content should be like this:

```
content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xml>
    <tag1>text</tag1>
    <tag2>text</tag2>
</xml>
```

But the result is always this:

```
content: 





     text
     text
```

Program code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        InputStream input;

        input = new FileInputStream(new File("D:/SolrTestFileSystem/Test_Files/test.xml"));

        ContentHandler textHandler = new WriteOutContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        parser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, context);
        input.close();
        System.out.println("content: " + textHandler.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xml>
    <tag1>text</tag1>
    <tag2>text</tag2>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using a text-only content handler to capture the content. If you want the XML tags, you need to use a content handler which keeps them!

(The fact that your content handler is called `textHandler` is a hint that the example you took it from wanted plain text!)

As taken from the [Apache Tika example for text and xhtml/xml extraction](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/ContentHandlerExample.java), your code should instead be:

```
import org.apache.tika.sax.ToXMLContentHandler;

InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(new File("D:/SolrTestFileSystem/Test_Files/test.xml"));
ContentHandler handler = new ToXMLContentHandler();

Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, context);

input.close();
System.out.println("content: " + handler.toString());
```

Comment: This solution seems also not work in the right way. The output with ToXMLContentHandler and XMLParser is, that the content is build in a html format with the body containing the extracted elements without the tags. I tried to use the TXTParser, and it seems to work right now, but i think that this is only a dirty solution.

Comment: If you just want the raw XML, why are you even using Tika? The point of Tika is to give you consistent metadata and xhtml/plain text from a range of formats

Comment: I imagine that, like me, the poster doesn't want the raw XML (I mean it's kind of obvious the poster doesn't want the raw XML!), but something more intelligent. 

Just using TXTParser doesn't unescape escape sequences, or remove special chars. 

For example
<Foo bar="barValue">
    Baz&lt;
</Foo>" 

Should be extracted as 
    Foo bar barValue Baz< Foo
or similar.

I'm unable to find any way to do this using standard Tika parsers/handlers, it appears that custom handlers need to be written, sadly.